# if dropdown is selected span is to show attribute of that option. This works until I add a second Select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
       $("#item1").change(function() {
          $('#price-
           displayitem1').text($('option:selected').attr('data-item1'));
       }).change();


      $("#item2").change(function() {
        $('#price-displayItem2').text($('option:selected').attr('data-item2'));
      }).change();
```

then here are the spans which will be chaged

```
<span id="price-displayItem1"></span>
<span id="price-displayItem2"></span>
```

Then here is the actual Select input

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="item1" style="color:black;">item1</label>
    <div class="input-select">
        <select name="item1" id="item1">
            <option value="1" data-item1="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" data-item1="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" data-item1="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="item2" style="color:black;">item2</label>
    <div class="input-select">
        <select name="item2" id="item2">
            <option value="1" data-item2="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" data-item2="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" data-item2="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: the id's and name's in actuality are only using string characters

Explanation: so basically It works for the first item/dropdown/span. But when I introduce a second or even third, then only the first one works properly. If i remove the code of the first. Then the second one begins to work but still not the third. and so on.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: because you are selecting all the option elements on the page...

Comment: Why use both the `data-item` and the `value` attributes if they both contain _exactly_ the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use selector before option.

```js
 $("#item1").change(function() {
          $('#price-displayitem1').text($('#item1 option:selected').attr('data-item1'));
       }).change();


      $("#item2").change(function() {
        $('#price-displayItem2').text($('#item2 option:selected').attr('data-item2'));
      }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="price-displayItem1"></span>
<span id="price-displayItem2"></span>


<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="item1" style="color:black;">item1</label>
    <div class="input-select">
        <select name="item1" id="item1">
            <option value="1" data-item1="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" data-item1="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" data-item1="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="item2" style="color:black;">item2</label>
    <div class="input-select">
        <select name="item2" id="item2">
            <option value="1" data-item2="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" data-item2="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" data-item2="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you use an option selector so you select all the options on the page.

```
$('option:selected').attr('data-item1')
```

so you need to look for the options in the select that you are using

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-item1')
```